# AG-grid Refresh Totals of pinned row

Tags: ag-grid

Please see this plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/cOuQ5YPdQDl6oDvoUSSn?p=preview
If i put filter on any column, eg from Gold i remove 8 then the total should get refreshed. How can this be achieved

enter code herefunction

```
CustomPinnedRowRenderer () {}

CustomPinnedRowRenderer.prototype.init = function(params) {
    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
    this.eGui.style = params.style;
    this.eGui.innerHTML = params.value;
};

CustomPinnedRowRenderer.prototype.getGui = function() {
    return this.eGui;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not updated cuz it doesn't relate with visible data, it's binding to real (immutable, memory data)

But for sure you can create a workaround and handle `pinnedData` by yourself

```
onFilterChanged:(params)=>{
    let result = {
        gold:0,
        silver:0,
        bronze:0
    }
    setTimeout(()=>{
        params.api.forEachNodeAfterFilter(i=>{
            result.gold += Number(i.data.gold);
            result.bronze += Number(i.data.bronze);
            result.silver += Number(i.data.silver);
        });
        console.log(result);
        params.api.setPinnedTopRowData([result]);
    },0)
}
```

Add this part to your `gridOptions`.

> One notice: currently we should use `setTimeout` inside `onFilterChanged` cuz `grid` doesn't provide updated data inside this event, the `ag-grid` team informed about
>
> AG-2078   Filter Cell Renderer refreshes before grid has finished updating